# Datagridview, go to cell

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a Datagridview where users can enter text. 
The cell must have a valid data on it, when it doesn't he will get a message how it should be and the edited value is canceled, which triggerd in the `CellLeave` event. When this happens I want the application to stay on this cell, but each time it goes (which the user select with the cursor or by pressing tab) but I want it to stay on the invalid cell.
When I search on this problem I get some solution like:

```
datagridview.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Selected = true;
```

or

```
datagridview.CurrentCell = datagridview.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
```

But no magic happens here. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the CellLeave event, try using the CellValidating event. If you cancel the event, I believe the DataGridView forces the user to amend the data before they can leave the cell.

The given `DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs` object should have the value you need in `e.FormattedValue` and can be cancelled if `e.Cancel` is set to true.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately it won't do the magic, it still goes to the next cell

Comment: It works correctly over here. Are you checking the value using `e.FormattedValue` and canceling with `e.Cancel = true`?

Comment: I need to better looking next time before I speak -.-'
I was hoped that it would fixed it with the code I gave, didn't looked at the e.Cancel (it's a shame) thanks :)

Comment: No problem. I'll amend the answer to make it clearer.